# macOS Mojave Installation Error

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mojave

I am getting a "macOS could not be installed on Your computer" message while installing OSX Mojave (the error comes up after Mojave asks to restart to proceed installation).

How do I install Mojave without erasing and performing a clean installation?

I've got the error log of that installation here. Regarding the keyboard messages at the end, I have an English International keyboard on my MacBook Pro 15" 2016.

I pasted the Installer log on Github because it blew the 30000 character limit here:
https://gist.github.com/mxmzb/68a643a5cc1ee4f6d0f88b84599909ad